# Apache Shiro - using database to read users, roles and permissions

Tags: java, shiro, jdbcrealm

Currently I've a Swing app and I wan't to integrate Apache Shiro in order to authenticate and delegate permissions to certain roles. I've already managed to read the users from the shiro.ini file that I've created for tests, it looks something like this:

```
[users]
admin = 123456, Administrator

[role]
Administrator = *:*:*
```

However this was just for testing, now I need to read the permits from a database so I've stored in a database a table with the info I need and it looks something like this:

```
users (id,password,username)
userRoles (userId, role)
rolePermission (permissionID,permission,roleID)
```

I've been trying to understand tutorials that use a JDBC realm, however they use web applications or specials frameworks to manage their connection to the Database like Apache Derby or BoneCP, and they confuse me even more with [these](http://meri-stuff.blogspot.com/2011/04/apache-shiro-part-2-realms-database-and.html) examples.

So what I'm asking it's how I need to configure the shiro.ini file if I wanna use a JDBC realm (with an Oracle database) and what classes the shiro.ini needs. Any examples or explanation will be appreciated!

Comment: Before I attempt an answer, do you know how to use JDBC and do you understand relational databases?

Comment: @BalusC not THEY, I said online examples, yes they are pretty straightforward, whenever you use the .ini file to get the users roles and permits, but no when you want to retrieve this information from a relational database

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm not an expert, but to my understanding JDBC it's an application programming interface that allows you to execute operations on database from Java language

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Realm` interface is a

> security component that can access application-specific security
>   entities such as users, roles, and permissions to determine
>   authentication and authorization operations.

You can implement it to interact with any source for finding users and their permissions. If you want to interact with an SQL-based database, you can do that. If you want to interact with a text file, you can do that. If you want to interact with a web service, you can do that, too.

There are two useful (almost necessary) extensions of `Realm` which are `AuthenticatingRealm` and `AuthorizingRealm`. They provide an interface for authentication and authorization services, respectively. `AuthorizingRealm` extends `AuthenticatingRealm`. You should extend `AuthorizingRealm` to implement your own authenticating and authorizing logic.

Take an example: You have a database with a table `Accounts` as

```
username | password | role
```

a table `Permissions` as

```
permission_id | permission_name
```

and a table `Account_Permissions`

```
username | permission_id
```

In other words, an `Account` can have one role, but multiple permissions. With JDBC you can very easily query such a database and retrieve usernames, passwords, roles, and permissions. Your implementation of `AuthorizingRealm` would do just that and construct objects expected by Shiro's API.

Read [this document](http://shiro.apache.org/authentication.html) on Shiro's authentication sequence to understand where the `AuthenticatingRealm` comes in.

As for the `INI` [file](http://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html), depending on how you implement your `Realm`, you would need to declare it as

```
myRealm = com.company.security.shiro.YourDatabaseRealm
```

possibly settings some properties

```
myRealm.databaseName = account_database
```

Shiro provides its own `JdbcRealm` class which extends `AuthorizingRealm`. This class makes some assumptions on the structure of your database, but you can customize it.

Comment: At the end I had to use BoneCP in order to provide a Data Source to Shiro, I was expecting to manage a connection without having to use any external libraries. Thank you for your patience on explaining it Was very helpful and at the end I managed to implement Shiro, and understand the concepts because of your brief over here.

Comment: @nivde92 You're welcome. Note that the above applies regardless of the `DataSource` you use. There are two different layers we're talking about.

Comment: The example tables only reflect *user-based* permissions, **not** *role-based* permissions. *Role-based* also typically implies that a subject can have multiple roles.